# Reading and writing pdf or binary data in C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm implementing `ftp` and I want to upload and download files, when I download or upload pdf files they are corrupted. How can handle reading any file, using `read()` and `write()` or `mmap`? below is my simplified code of what I have tried.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int     is_regular_file(const char *path)
{
    struct stat path_stat;

    stat(path, &path_stat);
    return (S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode));
}

int     ft_get_file_size(const char *filename)
{
    struct stat file;
    int         fd;

    if (!is_regular_file(filename))
        return (-1);
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    memset(&file, 0, sizeof(struct stat));
    fstat(fd, &file);
    close(fd);
    return (file.st_size);
}

char    *read_file(const char *filename)
{
    char    *content;
    int     file_size;
    int     fd;
    ssize_t retval;

    if ((file_size = ft_get_file_size(filename)) <= 0)
        return (NULL);
    content = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size + 1);
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    retval = read(fd, content, file_size);
    content[retval + 1] = '\0';
    close(fd);
    return (content);
}

void    write_file(char *file, char *content)
{
    int fd;

    fd = open(file, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd)
        write(fd, content, strlen(content));
    close(fd);
}

int main() {
    char *test = read_file("ftp.en.pdf");
    write_file("copy.pdf", test);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The process of downloading and uploading the file, is reading all the data from the file and then send that data to the socket. I have tried using `mmap` and I still get corrupted file.

> Document is damaged error message

[image: Corrupted file]

Comment: There are several problems with your code as written.  `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t`, not `int`.  The `st_size` element of a `struct stat` is an `off_t`, also not an `int`.  `fd = open(...); if ( fd ) ...` is also wrong.  `open()` returns `-1` on failure, which evaluates to true.  You also don't check the return values from `read()` nor `write()` to be sure the call actually read or wrote every byte you requested.

Comment: usually, when calling `read()` or `write()` they need to be called in a loop, using a sliding window for the data location, until all the data is read or written.

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest removing the cast.  2)  the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.   Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in `main()`, the returned value from: `read_file()` should be checked (!=NULL) as a way to avoid calling `write_file()`  Otherwise this statement: `write(fd, content, strlen(content));` will be trying to write from address 0 which will result in a seg fault event.   Also, if `content` contains a NUL byte, the actual amount written will be short.  Suggest using the same info as used to allocate the heap memory buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As binary data can have `\0` characters, you cannot treat your content as a string, so `strlen(content)` is wrong. You must return the size of the content from your `read_file` function.

For example, define your function as `char *read_file(const char *filename, int *size)` and return the size in `*size`. Likewise define your write function as `void write_file(char *file, char *content, int size)`

<sup>(and forget the +1 in malloc)</sup>